Oracle R2Jdbc hangs after 4 requests io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcTimeoutException: Connection acquisition timed out
I am using oracle reactive driver to connect oracle as below.
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ConnectionFactories.get(ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
                                                                                      .option(HOST, host)
                                                                                      .option(PORT, port)
                                                                                      .option(USER, userName)
                                                                                      .option(PASSWORD, password)
                                                                                      .option(DRIVER, driver) //driver is pool
                                                                                      .option(DATABASE, service)
                                                                                      .option(PROTOCOL, protocol) //protocol is oracle

I use Flux.when as below to execute query
Flux
                .usingWhen(con.getConnection(),
                        connection -> connection.createStatement(
                                "SELECT QUERY")

                                .execute(),
                        connection -> {
                            
                            return connection.close(); // Ensure it's returned to the pool
                        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flatMap(result -> result.map(row -> {
                    ResultDto rto = new ResultDto(row.get("x", String.class), row.get("c", Double.class),
                            row.get("y", String.class));
                    
                    return rto;
                })).doOnError(e -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("DB error on select", e);
                }).collectList().block();

This code executed for 4 requests.And 5th one through below error.
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcTimeoutException: Connection acquisition timed out after 10000ms
Caused by: io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcTimeoutException: Connection acquisition timed out after 10000ms

Please check why connection hangs after 4 successful requests.
Thanks
Isuru
I tried invoking a mule connector with oracle r2dbc in anypoint studio mule app

What driver and version? Is the code used inside a Mule application? How? Needs a [MRE].
